# Simple App Script to move a file from one bucket to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking to create a simple function to move a file from one bucket to another using app script.
Also with the option to delete the original file.
Does anyone already have a script that does this ?

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Check out: http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/googlecloud/gcsstore

Comment: Had a look at that, added the libraries as stated but got errors when tried to run anything. Would rather not use Goa and other 3rd party stuff.

Comment: You just asked for 3rd party stuff....`Does anyone already have a script that does this`. There are no google developed solutions its only 3rd party or your own code.

Comment: I got an error "could not find package" when trying to run Goa code examples. Does anyone just have a basic simple app script code ?

Answer (score 1):

Searching for something similar, also ended up at mcpher's but too much code for simple things.

I ended up finding those resources which might be helpful:

- [Use of a service account](https://ctrlq.org/code/20550-cloud-speech-api-with-service-account) (if you take this path you'll need [this OAuth2 object in your code too](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/dist/OAuth2.gs)
- [Use of oAuth2 tokens](https://ctrlq.org/code/20534-google-cloud-apps-script)

You can use this a basis to set things up, then use the Cloud Storage API (JSON) for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your encountered error, "could not find package", you may have missed installing the appropriate Cloud Client Library. Please check the installation instructions and reference material for the appropriate Cloud Client Library on your chosen [Cloud API](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/overview)’s Client Libraries page.

You may also check [Client Libraries Explained](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) for more information regarding Cloud Storage Client Libraries.

Furthermore, you may want to follow the steps in moving your data from one bucket to another as discussed in [Moving and Renaming Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets#storage-create-bucket-xml) which includes deleting the files from your old bucket.

Lastly, sample script is given in [Upload Files to Google Cloud Storage with Google Scripts](https://ctrlq.org/code/20074-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage) and discussed how to get started.

> To get started, you need to go to the Google Developer’s console and enable the Google Cloud Storage API and the Google Cloud Storage JSON Data API. Also enable billing for your account to access Google Cloud Storage. Then create the API keys (OAuth 2, Web Application) with the redirect URL containing your Google Apps Script project key. The OAuth2 library for Apps Script should also be included in your project.